# $.getJSON upload de imagem

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

Preciso fazer o upload da imagens junto com o cadastro no BD.

```
   $("#btnCriarConta").click(function() {
        if ($("#inputNomeCondominio").val() !== ""){

            var nomeCondominio  = "Tiago";
            var foto1 = "/data/data/com.intel.appx.IZICondominios.xwalk15/files/_pictures/picture_006.jpg";
            var operacao        = "addCondominio";
            $.getJSON("http://izicondominios.com.br/appOperacoes.php", {operacao:operacao,foto1:foto1}, function(json){

                var msg = json[0].msg;
                alert(msg);

            });

        }

});
```

Arquivo PHP **appOperacoes.php**:

```
if($_GET['operacao'] == 'ocorrenciaAdd'){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto1"]["tmp_name"], "ocorrencias/" . $_FILES["foto1"]["name"]);

    $rs = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO ocorrencias (id_condominio, foto) VALUES ('".$_GET["condominioID"]."', '".$_GET["foto1"]."' )");
    $registros = mysqli_num_rows($rs);

    if($rs){
        $arr[] = array('msg'=>'sucesso');
    }else{
        $arr[] = array('msg'=>'erro');
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);

    $mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema? O que não funciona? Que erros aparecem? O que fez pra tentar debugar?

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?